# h:selectOneMenu without value in composite component throws nullpointerexception

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, composite-component, selectonemenu, is-empty

I have a selectOneMenu in a composite component like this:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="label"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.label}" for="input"/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"  styleClass="width100">
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:message id="#{cc.attrs.id}-message" for="input" />  
</cc:implementation>
```

If I don't specify a value attribute when using this component:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:ezcomp="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/ezcomp"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:body>
            <h:form id="myform">
                <ezcomp:input label="Some label"  >
                </ezcomp:input>
                <p:commandButton value="Save" />
            </h:form>    
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

I get a nullpointerexception when submitting the form.:

```
12:25:23,882 FATAL [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-24) java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:866)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1290)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1290)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1290)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1290)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1254)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:654)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2466)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.put(UIComponentBase.java:2335)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.put(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.put(CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.java:331)
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.setValue(MapELResolver.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:255)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.setValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:172)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832)
    ... 38 more
```

I use jsf 2.2 (with Wildfly 9.0.1). If I use an inputText instead of a selectOneMenu it works well. It does not depend on the select not having options (it is not obvious from this example, but my original more complex one proved it), it defnitely depends on the selectOneMenu having an empty value attribute. It also works well if I specify a value, so it is not a huge problem, but makes things a bit more uncomfortable during development. Do you have any idea why it happens? Any solution, workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I reformatted the exception, it is indeed more readable